# Assigning the same event listener to multiple buttons

Tags: javascript

I've found that touchstart works better than the click event when working with my iPad, so I would like to use touchstart instead of 'click'.

Q: How do I refactor the JavaScript portion of the following? I used to have a single `$(document).on('click','.number',pgm.number)`

```js
pgm = {}
pgm.number = function() {
  console.log(this) // etc
}
btn1.addEventListener('touchstart', pgm.number, false)
btn2.addEventListener('touchstart', pgm.number, false)
btn3.addEventListener('touchstart', pgm.number, false)
btn4.addEventListener('touchstart', pgm.number, false)
btn5.addEventListener('touchstart', pgm.number, false)
btn6.addEventListener('touchstart', pgm.number, false)
btn7.addEventListener('touchstart', pgm.number, false)
btn8.addEventListener('touchstart', pgm.number, false)
btn9.addEventListener('touchstart', pgm.number, false)
btn0.addEventListener('touchstart', pgm.number, false)
```

```html
<button id="btn1" class="number">1</button>
<button id="btn2" class="number">2</button>
<button id="btn3" class="number">3</button>
<button id="btn4" class="number">4</button>
<button id="btn5" class="number">5</button>
<button id="btn6" class="number">6</button>
<button id="btn7" class="number">7</button>
<button id="btn8" class="number">8</button>
<button id="btn9" class="number">9</button>
<button id="btn0" class="number">0</button>
```

Comment: With jQuery this would be `$("button.number").on("touchstart", pgm.number, false)`.  You can probably do similar with vanilla JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `touchstart` to the document and use the event target to check if the element has the `className` `".number"`. This is the closest to jQuery's event delegation:

```
pgm.number = function(e) {
    var t = e.target;                               // get the taget of the event (the element that got touchstarted)
    if(t.classList.contains("number")) {            // if it has a class of .number
        console.log(t);                             // log it (use it)
    }
}

document.addEventListener("touchstart", pgm.number, false);
```

**Example using click:**

```js
var pgm = {};
pgm.number = function(e) {
  var t = e.target;
  if (t.classList.contains("number")) {
    console.log(t);
  }
}

document.addEventListener("click", pgm.number, false);
```

```html
<button id="btn1" class="number">1</button>
<button id="btn2" class="number">2</button>
<button id="btn3" class="number">3</button>
<button id="btn4" class="number">4</button>
<button id="btn5" class="number">5</button>
<button id="btn6" class="number">6</button>
<button id="btn7" class="number">7</button>
<button id="btn8" class="number">8</button>
<button id="btn9" class="number">9</button>
<button id="btn0" class="number">0</button>
```

Comment: I like this, but you have addEventListener("click" which needs to be changed to touchstart. That's one problem I'm having as well - click for my desktop browser, touchstart for my iPad.

Comment: The running code snippet is using the `click` event as a demonstration (as not everyone has an iPad). My solution using the `touchstart` event is above the snippet. As of the _whether to use `touchstart` or `click` event listener_ question, I think it should be a separate question.

Comment: Thanks ibrahim! This was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the buttons by class `number` and iterate over them using [**Array#forEach**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function and for each item add the event handler.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.number')
        .forEach(btn => btn .addEventListener('touchstart', pgm.number, false))
```

See an example

```js
function showId() {
   console.log(this.id) ;
}

document.querySelectorAll('.number')
            .forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', showId, false))
```

```html
<button id="btn1" class="number">1</button>
<button id="btn2" class="number">2</button>
<button id="btn3" class="number">3</button>
<button id="btn4" class="number">4</button>
<button id="btn5" class="number">5</button>
<button id="btn6" class="number">6</button>
<button id="btn7" class="number">7</button>
<button id="btn8" class="number">8</button>
<button id="btn9" class="number">9</button>
<button id="btn0" class="number">0</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.number');

buttons.forEach((button)=>{
  button.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{console.log(e.target)},false);
});
```

```html
<button id="btn1" class="number">1</button>
<button id="btn2" class="number">2</button>
<button id="btn3" class="number">3</button>
<button id="btn4" class="number">4</button>
<button id="btn5" class="number">5</button>
<button id="btn6" class="number">6</button>
<button id="btn7" class="number">7</button>
<button id="btn8" class="number">8</button>
<button id="btn9" class="number">9</button>
<button id="btn0" class="number">0</button>
```

It's sample code.

I hope it help you.

Comment: The selector should be `.number`, like in his original jQuery.